# Object of type 'System.DBNull' cannot be converted to type 'System.DateTime'

Tags: c#, winforms

How can I pass null values to a system.datetime?

```
try
        {
            List<T> listData = new List<T>();
            string connectionstring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connetionString"].ConnectionString;
            NpgsqlConnection MyConnection = new NpgsqlConnection(connectionstring);
            MyConnection.Open();
            NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand(string.Concat(query, table), MyConnection);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.Connection = MyConnection;
            NpgsqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                T objCodeName = new T();
                PropertyInfo[] properties = objCodeName.GetType().GetProperties();
                foreach (PropertyInfo prop in properties)
                {
                    prop.SetValue(objCodeName, dr[prop.Name]);
                }
                listData.Add(objCodeName);
            }
            dr.Close();
            Message message = new Message();
            message.data = listData;
            return message;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Message message = new Message();
            message.message = e.Message;
            return message;
        }
```

Comment: you can set `DateTime.MinValue` as your null value or change your type to `DateTime?`

Comment: where is the `DateTime` type used? is it the `T` in `List<T>`? where is the `Db.Null` value used? is it in `SetValue`? please provide accurate information so we can help

Comment: Consider throwing away most of this and replacing it with Dapper. There's no good reason to write this boilerplate yourself in 2022.

Comment: @Jon the property should be nullable, `DateTime?`, then when the database value is DBNull, then just assign null to the property.  It basically is something that could be done using an ORM like Entity Framework.

Answer (score 1):

You can check for `DBNull` while accessing your data reader values like this:

```
while (dr.Read())
{
    T objCodeName = new T();
    PropertyInfo[] properties = objCodeName.GetType().GetProperties();
    foreach (PropertyInfo prop in properties)
    {
        if (!(dr["prop.Name"] is DBNull))
        {
            prop.SetValue(objCodeName, dr[prop.Name]);  
        }
    }
    listData.Add(objCodeName);
}
```